# Looping over arrays

Tags: javascript, loops

Complete the `sumNumbers` function. This function should:

- return the sum of all numbers inside of the array that is passed to the function
- if the array is empty, this function should return 0

For example:

```
sumNumbers([1, 2, 3]) // should return 6
```

My Code:

```
sumNumbers = function(sum) {
    var sumArray = [1, 2, 3];
    for (var i = sumArray; i < 7; i ++)
        return sum
};
```

I tested my code through the terminal and it passed for defining sum numbers but I couldn't get it to pass for getting the sum for consecutive numbers. Any insight or helpful tips would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **loop over your array**.

Something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {

   sum += sumArray[i];
}
```